# Multiple filter and formatting issue

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to send logs from td-agent to Datadog using the below configuration. My expectation is filtering some keywords and formating that logs with using CSV format type. How can I do this?

I tried to grep and format plugin in the filter section as below but it doesn't work as expected. The current and expected situation as below picture. How can I solve this situation?

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 8888
  tag rsyslog
</source>

<filter rsyslog.**>
  @type grep
  <regexp>
      key message
      pattern /COMMAND/
  </regexp>
  <format>
      @type csv
      fields hostname,from,to
  </format>
</filter>

<match rsyslog.**>
  @type datadog
  @id awesome_agent
  api_key xxxxxxxxxx
</match>
```

[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay7Dv.png)

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imQff.png)

Comment: Please elaborate "it doesn't work as expected".

Comment: @NishantAgarwal added 2 pics for current and expected situations